# Binding a backbone view to html already renderer

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a fancy way of binding a view to html already renderer in the page?

Example your server load all your page html, then you load views on top of that html without using the render method the first time you load the page.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.  Since JavaScript is client-side any JS framework can modify DOM elements without having to rely on the server (unless you are using services to load AJAX related data).  That's the whole idea behind single-page applications - the server sends one html view that contains all the templates and the JavaScript renders the views and manipulates the html.  Could you describe a little more specifically what you are working on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done something similar to what I think you're trying to do. In my case, I added Backbone functionality on top of existing forms. Here's a stripped down example:

Existing HTML:

```
<div id="my-app">
  <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form> 
</div>
```

Backbone:

```
var MyFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "submit form": "formHandler"
  },
  formHandler: function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var nameVal = $('#username').val();
    this.$el.append('<p>hello: ' + nameVal + '</p>');
  }
});

$().ready(function(){
  var myForm = new MyFormView({el: "#my-app"});
});
```

The key is passing your existing html as the "el" property when you create your view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a *fancy* method, but your views don't need to render the `html` for their `el` themselves. You can easily attach a view to an existing element on the page just by assigning it to it's [el](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el). If you want to assign your view's el at a later point (say you want to "*switch*" its `el`) then you can use the [setElement](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) method to do so. Using the `setElement` will also create the cached `$el` and move over any bound events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are currently working on, but I made a JSFiddle that utilizes only Backbone Views - no Models or Collections or Routers to worry about.

You can play around with this and see how the main page view is being loaded into its container.

Here is the Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/tVmTM/71/